# SQL and PHP - time restriction implementation

Tags: php, mysql

context:
i have a website where users can make "bets" on events, they can't bet when the event starts, and 1 day prior to it.

My first approach was add a timestamp to the bet in the table, and then comparing with a timestamp of the event and ignore when xtime < ytime.

from what I've read from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

> Tip: To keep your queries simple and easy to maintain, do not allow time components in your dates!

So... only by day seems kind of awkward, or is this tip nonsense?

I also thought in locking bets for a schedule time, but making the site "unusable" for 2/3 days seems like a not good idea.

Is my first approach the right one, or is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: Block illegal betting times in your UI, and then make sure your PHP code also checks for this, e.g. in case someone hacked the UI.  I don't think you need any special handling in MySQL for this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My problem is that the event will only be recorded after it happened, so i can take bets but they would only be applicable for the next week. (they are weekly).

Comment: Assuming that there can be events where the bets would be time based not just date based so I would suggest going ahead with your first approach, more sensible & flexible.